# does Pseudo Mercator Projection causes problem while clipping rasters

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I tryed to clip a Raster file using an ESRI shapefile using gdalwarp command, but i always get an empty output file or a wrong clip with wrong location.
this the command bellow:

```
gdalwarp -dstnodata -999 -q -s_srs '+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +units=m +no_defs' -t_srs 'EPSG:3857' -cutline mask.shp -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff inputRaster.tif outputRaster.tif
```

Comment: is your shp also in mercator ?

Comment: yes it is in pseudo mercator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit tricky to crop and reproject the tif in one step. Better try the clipping first, then the reprojection.

I had some problems with clipping in EPSG:3857 too. This might be due to the special treatment of the Google Mercator CRS. If possible, convert tif and shapefile to another (and the same!) CRS, like UTM of your part of the world, or EPSG:4326.